# SCons Action Verbosity Levels

Tags: shell, scons, verbosity

Given that my Ada builder use a function `ada_action` which is registered by

```
static_obj.action(suffix, Action(ada_action, print_action_string)
```

which currently calls `env.Execute()` and further

```
def print_action_string(target, source, env):
    print env.subst(env["ADACOMSTR"], target=target, source=source)
```

How can I control the verbosity levels so that if `env["ADACOMSTR"]` is defined it should only call `print_action_string` and inhibit echoing of the shell command currently done by `env.Execute()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally don't need to use Execute() in a builder action.  Perhaps if you share that bit of code it might help.  You could also look into using a generator, depending on what exactly you're looking for.

Comment: Ok, so I guess I should use Python's own builtin shell commands and echo it manually (when in my case flag `VERBOSE=on`) prior to shell call?

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable approach.